# Multiple row count from single table

Tags: sql, select, db2

How do I get counts of multiple records from a single table using db2 query?

Suppose I want to get the count of 1 record am using:

```
select count(*) from schema.table where record value='x'
```

What I need is a count of multiple records from the same table in separate rows for each record. I am trying something like:

```
select count(*) from schema.table where record in('x','y','z')
```

The queried result combines the value into one single value in a single row, which I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `group by` syntax breaks the table up into groups, and allows you to perform aggregate functions (`count`, in your case) on each one separately:

```
SELECT   record, COUNT(*)
FROM     schema.table
GROUP BY record
```

Answer (score 2):

I almost agree with the Mureinik.  You can add a `WHERE` clause to get multiple row counts from only those records you want, e.g. (x, y, z)

```
SELECT record, COUNT(*) AS 'count'
FROM schema.table WHERE record IN ('x', 'y', 'z')
GROUP BY record
```

**result:**

```
------------------
| record | count |
------------------
|   x    |  100  |
|   y    |  150  |
|   z    |  50   |
------------------
```

Comment: should be `WHERE record in ('x','y','z')`  There no point in the group by if you're only selecting a single record value.

Comment: @Charles Thanks for the correction.  I was trying to avoid the situation WHERE (no pun intended) you might get back dozens of groups requiring you to sift through in order to get what you want.